Thought experiment regarding gravity
Let there be a mass $M$ which is a spherical shell of radius $R$.
Now the Gaussian flux about a enclosing sphere of radius $r$ where $r>R$ will be proportional to $M$ or $GM$ (where $G$ is the gravitational constant).
Now if this mass were distributed to R' where R'>R some work will have to be done so we can use some part of this mass M itself,convert to energy and be left with M' where M' < M.
However a person outside this whole arragement , say at a distance D where D> R and D > R' should not be able to feel any difference by this change.(This argument is similar to the hypotheses of there being no experiment to distinguish between free fall and uniform motion without any influence of gravity.) So the mass that this person sees will be different from both M and M'.
Does it imply that the mass one sees is dependent on the distance from that mass object? and also does it imply that gravitation field falls faster than 1/r^2?

If an observer of mass m is at distance d from a mass M, and then he moves to a distance d'(d' > d), there has to be work done to raise his altitude and lets say this work or energy is sourced from M, leading to a drop in M to M'. However no local gravitational measurement would change for the observer is my hypotheses. So he still sees the original mass M but when getting closer to the other object we see that the mass is slightly lesser than M. Whats wrong with this argument?


Now if this mass were distributed to R' where R'>R some work will have to be done so we can use some part of this mass M itself,convert to energy and be left with M' where M' < M.

The key error in the reasoning lies here. In this statement you are trying to misuse the famous equation $E=mc^2$. It does not describe converting mass to energy; conversion would be $\Delta E=-\Delta m c^2$. The famous equation describes the equivalence of mass and energy. Mass does not need to be converted to energy, it already has energy. Similarly energy has mass, no conversion needed.
Note that the famous equation only applies for a system with no overall momentum. This system meets that criterion, so it applies. Therefore, no amount of internal rearrangement can change the mass or energy of the system. So $M’=M$.
The only way for $M$ to change would be for mass or energy to cross the boundary of the system. If it accretes some dust then $M$ will increase as will the energy. If it radiates some EM waves then the energy will decrease as will $M$.

Does it imply that the mass one sees is dependent on the distance from that mass object? and also does it imply that gravitation field falls faster than 1/r^2?

No. None of the subsequent reasoning holds once the error in the use of the famous $E=mc^2$ equation is corrected.

I see that I downvoted this, but it must have been accidental.  I tried to correct that, but apparently I can't change my vote unless/until this is edited.  My apologies!

@WillO no worries. Mis-clicks happen

Corrected now!..

@WillO Thanks

Yes but what about the negative energy of the gravitational field. The farther one is from the mass, the more this negative energy. So total flux would be lesser than M at a distance.

Flux doesn’t work that way in Newtonian gravity and the energy of the gravitational field is not localizable in general relativity.

What Im saying is the mass would depend on where you are in the gravitational field while measuring it

Yes. I understood clearly what you are saying

First of all, your gedankenexperiment is actually fairly realistic (if we consider spheres instead of shells). Imagine for example a star in the center of which occurs nuclear fusion. This is literally the conversion of part of the (rest) mass of the "fuel", e.g. hydrogen, into energy in the form of radiation. As this happens at the center of the star, the radiation can't escape immediately and exerts pressure. Usually, a star is in equilibrium, meaning that the radiation pressure together with the gas pressure stabilizes the star against gravitational collapse. However, in some situations (through very complicated processes), the internal pressure gets higher than the gravitational attraction such that the star expands, for example at the end of its life when it turns into a red giant. Some stars even change their radius periodically.
The solution to your problem lies in the fact that we have to be very careful which mass we are actually talking about. For one thing, there is the so called baryonic mass, which is just the sum of all the masses of the constituents of the star. Imagine taking the star apart into its atoms, measuring their individual masses and adding them. But this is not equal to the gravitational mass of the star, which is used in Newton's gravitational law to calculate the gravitational field that an outside observer measures. The discrepancy between those two values stems in fact again from mass-energy equivalence. The gravitational mass of the star corresponds to its total energy, which includes the rest mass of its constituents, but also its binding energy (and other forms of energy like the heat trapped inside and all other kinds of interaction energy between the constituents, but I will neglect this here). To put this into an equation:
\begin{equation}
M = M_B + E_B
\end{equation}
where $M$ is the gravitational mass, $M_B$ is the baryonic mass and $E_B$ is the binding energy (note that I choose the signs such that the binding energy is negative). In our example, the star expanded, which just means that it raised its binding energy. In other words, it converted part of its baryonic mass into binding energy. However, as we neglected any incoming or outgoing energy flux, the gravitational mass of the star (which, again, corresponds to its total energy content) stays constant! So an outside observer won't feel a difference, he will still measure the same gravitational mass.
Finally, let me note that we're talking about small effects here, at least considering "normal" stars. They stem from general relativity, which makes sense, as we used mass-energy equivalence, which is a relativistic effect. The situation we discussed is described by the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkoff equation. You can find a more mathematical discussion of this topic, including the different "kinds" of masses in the referenced Wikipedia article.

I chose a shell so that there is symmetry across each point of the mass..in a sphere, the varying factor would be distance from the centre

What about the mass of the gravitational field itself??? The field has negative energy and would this not be more and more as one distances from the mass.

The gravitational field itself does not have any mass. In fact, it does not even have an energy (in the context of general relativity) in the sense that it would contribute to the energy-momentum tensor, which is the source of the gravitational field. All the effects of the gravitational field influencing itself are already encoded in Einstein's field equations, specifically in the fact that they are nonlinear. So in other terms: No, we don't need to additionally consider any concept of "gravitational field energy", my treatment is fine as is.

Also note that the gravitational binding energy I talk about in my answer isn't something we explicitly include in solving the Einstein field equations either. It is implicitly encoded in the Einstein field equations already, even though, again, the energy-momentum tensor appearing there does not contain any terms depending on the gravitational field.

I dont think that is what https://www.einstein-online.info/en/spotlight/gravity_of_gravity/ is saying. Please check non linearity of gravity. I might be wrong..Im unfamiliar with GR math

No, that's exactly what I'm saying. I think you misunderstood my comments. Gravity does interact with itself, this manifests itself by the Einstein equations being nonlinear. I just wanted to convey to you that gravity influencing itself is encoded in the curvature tensor (the lefthand side of Einstein's field equations so to speak) and not in the energy-momentum tensor (the righthand side of Einstein's field equations).

Maybe I understand what your actual question is now. So let me rephrase it, please tell me if that is what you are asking: "Consider two observers who only know about Newton's law of gravity (the 1/r^2 law), one stationed at distance $R$ and one at distance $R' > R$ from a star. If they know their distance from the star, and if they measure the gravitational "force" on a test particle (of which they know the mass), they can calculate the mass of the star. From this analysis, do the two observers calculate the same mass for the star?"

The answer to this would actually be no, as you (I think) suggested. The reason for this is that Newton's 1/r^2 law isn't completely accurate. If we consider the problem in the context of GR, the solution of Einstein's field equations outside of a (spherically symmetric) star is the Schwarzschild metric. We can actually formulate this solution in a way such that it can pretty straight forwardly be compared to Newton's law, see e.g. here. It turns out that...

interpreting gravity as a force for a second, Newton's law is modified by a (usually small, at least for ordinary stars) negative correction term that scales with 1/r^4 (if my understanding is correct). So if our observers from the beginning naively apply Newton's law to calculate the mass of the star, they will get different masses depending on their position, because they didn't consider the correction term.

Finally, note that this GR correction (I think) is at least partially due to the nonlinearity of Einstein's equations, which, again, describes how gravity interacts with itsself (so in a sense describes the "energy of the gravitational field" although as I already explained I think this terminology is misleasing). One would need to conduct a more thorough analysis though to find out exactly if and how this "gravitational field energy" causes the GR correction.

How would the electric field of a charge q placed on the mass m fall with r? You mentioned for gravity there is a correction factor of the order of 1/r^4

I don't know, please ask a seperate question for this.

Let's look at this mathematically. Let $\vec{g} \equiv \vec{g}(r)$ be the gravitational field. Then Gauss' law in its differential form states
$$\operatorname{div} \vec{g} \enspace = \enspace - 4\pi G \rho$$
where $G$ is the gravitational constant and $\rho$ is the mass density. Integration of this equation over a ball of radius $r$ gives for the left-hand side
$$\int_{B(r)} \! dV \,\operatorname{div} \mathbf{g} \enspace = \enspace \oint_{S(r)} \! d\vec{A} \cdot \vec{g} \enspace = \enspace 4\pi r^2 \, g(r)$$
and for the right-hand side
$$-4\pi G \int_{B(r)} \! dV \, \rho \enspace = \enspace -4\pi G M$$
with $M$ being the total mass. Together one finds
$$g(r) \enspace = \enspace - \frac{GM}{r^2}$$
This means, assuming the observer is located at distance $D > R' > R$, that the radius $R$ of the shell has no influence on the field experienced by the observer. Therefore it does not matter whether the shell has radius $R$ or radius $R'$, as long as both are smaller than $D$. The only thing the observer would experience, is a change in mass. Assuming the system somehow reduces in mass from $M$ to $M'$, the observer will experience a field
$$g(r) \enspace = \enspace - \frac{GM'}{r^2}$$
so that indeed he sees the "new" mass $M'$ as it is.

I still think the mass of the sun would be different based on gravitational field of the Sun detected at say Mercury vs Pluto. This because the gravitational field has negative energy. So as one travels from Mercury to Pluto, the total Gaussian flux across an enclosing sphere would keep falling as the distance from the Sun increases. This is also expected if we consider conservation of energy. Maybe my original question was not rightly phrased. Apologies.
